# Install plugin as locally instead of site

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have created a sample plug-in and I have them as folders like this:

- Features
- Plugins
- Artifacts.jar
- Content.jar

So I copied the features and plug-in in to the respective folder of Eclipse install. But still I didn’t see the plugin.

So one of my colleague told me to install software using site, I don’t know how to create site. Instead I want install as locally. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use 'File > Export' and select 'Plug-in Development > Deployable Features' to create a directory or archive file.

Then use the 'Install New Software...' dialog. Click 'Add...' and use 'Local..' if you have a directory or 'Archive...' if you have an archive.

You may need to deselect the 'Group items by category' check box to see the contents of your install.